# send device token to server

Tags: iphone, token, devicetoken

I have read a lot of tutorials for this and i just wanted ti know if this is right way to do this

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);

    NSString* newToken = [deviceToken description];

    newToken = [newToken stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    newToken = [newToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]; 


    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myhost.com./filecreate.php?token=%@",newToken];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSData *urlData;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];

}
```

any advices are more then welcomed.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{

    const char* data = [deviceToken bytes];
    NSMutableString* token = [NSMutableString string];

    for (int i = 0; i < [deviceToken length]; i++) {
        [token appendFormat:@"%02.2hhX", data[i]];
    }


    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myhost.com/filecreate.php?token=%@",token];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];   
    NSData *urlData;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];

}
```

My application works with both codes, but what's the right way?

Comment: looks fine, but, i would 1, add error recovery mechanism (if the request fails you will lose your token!) and b, use asynchronous request.

Comment: asynchronous? how do you mean.Please give me some guide lines for the error recovery mechanism also. The code works but I was wondering if this is the right way, cause I have read somewhere that `NSString* newToken = [deviceToken description];` this is not the right way to get data into string

Comment: Does your code work? I did the same thing but my device token became `(null)` when I send it to the server?

Comment: @tnylee are you getting it in the NSLog?Try printing "urlString" just before sending to server and see. Print the response to see what happens on the server side.

Comment: @Spire Yes I am getting it in NSLog, I removed the "<" ">" " " signs too. It still is `(null)`.

Comment: @Spire I had it working! I forgot to put "+" in between for spaces. Thanks for trying to help! :D

Comment: @tnylee No prob, glad you solve it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As *mja* said in comments, it's better to add error recovery mechanism (if the request fails you will lose your token) and use asynchronous request (send token in background)

In your AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSString * token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];
    //Format token as you need:
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:token forKey:@"apnsToken"]; //save token to resend it if request fails
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"apnsTokenSentSuccessfully"]; // set flag for request status
    [DataUpdater sendUserToken]; //send token
}
```

To send token create new class (or use one of existing): 
**DataUpdater.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DataUpdater : NSObject     
+ (void)sendUserToken;
@end
```

**DataUpdater.m**

```
#import "DataUpdater.h"

@implementation DataUpdater

+ (void)sendUserToken {
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"apnsTokenSentSuccessfully"]) {
        NSLog(@"apnsTokenSentSuccessfully already");
        return;
    }

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myhost.com/filecreate.php?token=%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"apnsToken"]]]; //set here your URL

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error == nil) {
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"apnsTokenSentSuccessfully"];
             NSLog(@"Token is being sent successfully");
             //you can check server response here if you need
         }
     }];
}

@end
```

Then you can call **[DataUpdater sendUserToken];** in your controllers when internet connection appears, or periodically, or in **-(void)viewDidLoad** or **-(void)viewWillAppear** methods

My advises:

1) I use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to send async request and check server JSON response

2) Some times it's better to use services such as [Parse](https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/iOS) to work with push notifications

Comment: Thx dude but this is very very old question. Ill accept the answer, it might benefit someone.

Comment: I think you should call [synchronize](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsuserdefaults_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/synchronize) after storing the info.

Answer (score 0):

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

After doing above lines of code ,add the method below

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Push Notifications
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
NSString  *token_string = [[[[deviceToken description]    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]
                            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
                           stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
NSString* strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.sample.com?device_token=%@&type=IOS",token_string];
strURL=[strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",strURL);
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
NSLog(@"content---%@", fileData);
}
```

Comment: The code in didFinishLaunchingWithoptions must add to get the push notifications